# Django upgrade from 1.4 to 1.8

Tags: python, django, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade a project from Django 1.4 to 1.8.  I've adjusted the app definitions [as the docs say to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/):

wm/apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class WMConfig(AppConfig):
    name="wm"
    verbose_name="WebManager"
```

wm/__init__.py:

```
default_app_config = 'wm.apps.WMConfig'
```

The issue is now when I try to access the app through a browser I get a 500 error.  The Apache logs show:

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=33242): Target WSGI script '/home/admusr/project/WebManager/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=33242): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/admusr/project/WebManager/wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/admusr/project/WebManager/wsgi.py", line 24, in <module>
     application = get_wsgi_application()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 112, in create
     mod = import_module(mod_path)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
     __import__(name)
 ImportError: No module named wm.apps
```

If I change wm/__init__.py to `default_app_config = 'apps.WMConfig'` then it just says `ImportError: No module named apps`, so the issue is when it tried to load that module.  I haven't been able to find anything on this with such a generic error message.

Comment: What's your project layout, and how does the app appear in your INSTALLED_APPS setting?

Comment: `project` is the root dir (containing manage.py), then `project/WebManager` contains settings.py, where `INSTALLED_APPS` is defined, and `project/WebManager/wm` is the wm app.  the app is listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` as `'WebManager.wm'`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
default_app_config = 'Webmanager.wm.apps.WMConfig'
```

As an aside, [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#configuring-applications) recommend that you use the path to the app config directly in `INSTALLED_APPS`, instead of seeing `default_app_config` in the app's `__init__.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ... 
    'Webmanager.wm.apps.WMConfig',
```

)

The other problem is your app config's [`name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.name) attribute. This should be the *full path*, i.e. `WebManager.wm` instead of `wm`.

```
class WMConfig(AppConfig):
    name="WebManager.wm"
    verbose_name="WebManager"
```

Comment: I'm now getting the same error, except instead of `No module named wm.apps` it's just `No module named wm`

Comment: Very late reply, but I believe the other problem is the app config's `name`. It should be `WebManager.wm`, not `wm`.